# Uploading images to amazon S3 using Phoenix/elixir and Arc

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir, phoenix-framework

Hey I am having problems getting Arc to upload images to my amazon S3 account. I don't know if the problem is configuring the app to connect to the account properly or how to set the upload file correctly. I have tried a few ways of doing things and have not had success.

First, I tried hard setting my key ID and Secret access key in a `secret.config.exs` file like so:

```
 config :ex_aws,
  access_key_id: "My key ID was here",
  secret_access_key: "My secret access key was here",
    region: "us-west-2",
 s3: [
scheme: "https://",
host: "s3.amazonaws.com",
region: "us-west-2"
]
```

But no success. I tried again to set them in the config file using system environment variables like this:

```
config :arc,
bucket: "callmemd"
config :ex_aws,
access_key_id: [{:system, "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"}, :instance_role],
secret_access_key: [{:system, "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"}, :instance_role]
```

But, I am not sure I did that correctly. This is the code in the controller I am trying to use to call the upload with the uploaded file being saved properly in a param named avatar as an upload plug:

```
 def create(conn, %{"doctor" => doctor_params}) do
 avatar = doctor_params["avatar"]
 Myapp.Avatar.store({avatar.filename, avatar.path})
```

I have also tried the following different configurations and many other variations with no luck:

```
 Callme.Avatar.store({doctor_params["avatar"], doctor_params["id"]})
 Callme.Avatar.store({%Plug.Upload{doctor_params}, doctor_params["id"]})
 Callme.Avatar.store({%Plug.Upload{}, doctor_params["id"]})
 Callme.Avatar.store({doctor_params["avatar"], doctor_params["id"]})
```

Here are my dependencies

```
 defp deps do
[{:phoenix, "~> 1.1.4"},
 {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
 {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 2.0"},
 {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.4"},
 {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
 {:gettext, "~> 0.9"},
 {:comeonin, "~> 1.0"},
 {:mailgun, "~> 0.1.2"},
 {:poison, "~> 2.1", override: true},
 {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
 {:arc, "~> 0.5.2"},
 {:ex_aws, "~> 0.4.10"},
 {:httpoison, "~> 0.7"}]
 end
```

Mix file:

```
  def application do
[mod: {Callme, []},
 applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :ex_aws, :httpoison, :logger, :gettext, :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex]]
end
```

Log when Create action is invoked successfully:

```
[info] POST /doctors
[debug] SELECT u0."id", u0."name", u0."email", u0."crypted_password", u0."admin", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at" FROM "users" AS u0 WHERE (u0."id" = $1) [26] OK query=0.0ms
[debug] Processing by Callme.DoctorController.create/2
Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "XxEtCRshOjg5Wj1ZLwIzWmYzPwYBJgAAmtGqxfcHa3q1mOF8WfGDLQ==", "_utf8" => "✓", "doctor" => %{"avatar" => %Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/jpeg", filename: "beta.jpg", path: "C:\\Users\\Frank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/plug-1469/multipart-622422-206000-2"}, "bio" => "bio", "hiddeninfo" => "hiddeninfo", "name" => "name", "picture" => "picture", "specialty" => "specialty"}}
Pipelines: [:browser]
[debug] BEGIN [] OK query=0.0ms
[debug] INSERT INTO "doctors" ("inserted_at", "updated_at", "bio", "hiddeninfo", "name", "picture", "specialty") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id" [{{2016, 7, 27}, {12, 27, 2, 0}}, {{2016, 7, 27}, {12, 27, 2, 0}}, "bio", "hiddeninfo", "name", "picture", "specialty"] OK query=0.0ms
[debug] COMMIT [] OK query=16.0ms
[info] Sent 302 in 32ms
[info] GET /doctors
[debug] SELECT u0."id", u0."name", u0."email", u0."crypted_password", u0."admin", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at" FROM "users" AS u0 WHERE (u0."id" = $1) [26] OK query=0.0ms
 [debug] Processing by Callme.DoctorController.index/2
 Parameters: %{}
 Pipelines: [:browser]
 [debug] SELECT d0."id", d0."name", d0."hiddeninfo", d0."bio", d0."specialty", d0."picture", d0."inserted_at", d0."updated_at" FROM "doctors" AS d0 [] OK query=0.0ms
```

I adjusted the code a little bit and now I am getting the error as follows

```
Request: POST /doctors 
Jul 28 10:28:37 callmemd app/web.1:  ** (exit) an exception was raised: 
Jul 28 10:28:37 callmemd app/web.1:      ** (KeyError) key :id not found in: %Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/jpeg", filename: "file000166349580.jpg", path: "/tmp/plug-1469/multipart-726916-266069-2"} 
Jul 28 10:28:37 callmemd app/web.1:          (callme) web/controllers/doctor_controller.ex:21: Callme.DoctorController.create/2 
Jul 28 10:28:37 callmemd app/web.1:          (callme) web/controllers/doctor_controller.ex:1: Callme.DoctorController.action/2 
Jul 28 10:28:37 callmemd app/web.1:          (callme) web/controllers/doctor_controller.ex:1: Callme.DoctorController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2 
Jul 28 10:28:37 callmemd app/web.1:          (callme) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: Callme.Router.dispatch/2 
Jul 28 10:28:37 callmemd app/web.1:          (callme) web/router.ex:1: Callme.Router.do_call/2 
Jul 28 10:28:37 callmemd app/web.1:          (callme) lib/callme/endpoint.ex:1: Callme.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1 
Jul 28 10:28:37 callmemd app/web.1:          (callme) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:34: Callme.Endpoint.call/2
```

One problem was the variable for the amazon ID was named incorrectly for my system variable which I changed. Now I am trying with the controller code being as follows:

```
  def create(conn, %{"doctor" => doctor_params}) do
changeset = Doctor.changeset(%Doctor{}, doctor_params)
avatar = doctor_params["avatar"]
Callme.Avatar.store({%Plug.Upload{}, id: avatar.id})
```

Comment: Also, here's the working example: https://github.com/elixir-lang-moscow/site/blob/master/web/uploaders/avatar.ex